# IndexError: list index out of range, python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem I try to solve is this: "Given an array of integers, find the pair of adjacent elements that has the largest product and return that product."

This is my code but it says that "IndexError: list index out of range"

```
def solution(inputArray):
    largest_product = 0
    x = 0
    y = 0
    length_of_array = len(inputArray)
    
    if(length_of_array < 2):
        return
    
    for i in range(len(inputArray)):
        x = inputArray[i]
        y = inputArray[i+1]
        
        if(x * y > largest_product):
            largest_product = x * y
            
    return largest_product


inputArray = [3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]
```

Comment: _Hint:_  When there are **6 elements**, you should be looping for **5 iterations**.

Comment: A more idiomatic solution is to use `zip` and `max` builtins. For example `max(x*y for x,y in zip(inputArray[:-1],inputArray[1:]))`

Comment: it's because you assign `inputArray[i+1]` to `y`, but `i` will eventually become the last index. By doing `[i+1]`, you try to access one index beyond the last of the array. Another hint I'd give you - try to run the case where `inputArray = [-1, 2, -3, 4, -5, 6]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you get `IndexError: list index out of range` because you try to access an item that doesn't exists - `y = inputArray[i + 1] = inputArray[6] = not exists`

```
def solution(inputArray):
    largest_product = 0
    x = 0
    y = 0
    length_of_array = len(inputArray)

    if (length_of_array < 2):
        return

    for i in range(len(inputArray)-1):
        x = inputArray[i]
        y = inputArray[i + 1]

        if (x * y > largest_product):
            largest_product = x * y

    return largest_product
```

you have an easier to do it using `zip` and `max:

```
max(x*y for x,y in zip(inputArray[:-1],inputArray[1:]))
```